# Host Nodejs and PHP on same server

Tags: php, node.js, hosting

I am creating a **browser based multiplayer quiz game**. I am writing most of the code in PHP e.g. Uploading questions, User Profiles Etc. But the *Quiz part*, I am creating it with **Nodejs and Socket.io**. My PHP pages requests on node server with help of socket.io.
It is working totally fine in localhost, **but how do I put it online**? on same server? or different servers? or Domains? I am not able to figure out how I can put my website online. Please guide me how I can do this:)

Comment: it could all be in the same server, yes (and it will almost certainly be a lot simpler if it is). You'd need to find a host which can run both PHP and Node simultaneously, or rent a virtual server of your own (or a cloud-based serverless hosting) and configure the environment. P.S. It's usually wise to consider your deployment options at the point where you're deciding what technologies you'll use to build the app - i.e. _before_ you start coding. No point building something if you can't deploy it to a live environment, or it's too expensive to do so.

Comment: P.S. Why didn't you just write the websockets part using PHP? or write the whole thing using Node?

Comment: @ADyson Can you guide me how can I host both? I have already written node server and PHP client files. What do you suggest me to do? Should I configure PHP web sockets from scratch instead of node server? Or can you guide me how I can use PHP websockets??

Comment: @ADyson if I do write php websockets  .. will it give me speed like node js??

Comment: That probably depends on what implementation you use, and other factors. But in theory there's no reason why not. What specifically are you concerned about?